# How do I use the taskbar button to display a progress bar?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc, taskbar

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to update an application. The application was written 15 years ago, and I would like to add a progress bar overlay to the taskbar button, something that Windows 7 now provides. I have followed all the tutorials I can find, such as

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/SevenGoodiesTaskbarStatus.aspx

and

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80082/Windows-How-to-display-progress-bar-on-taskbar-i

However they both seem to use outdated namespaces, such as 
`MESSAGE_HANDLER_EX` which gives me a whole bunch of errors. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: See this article on msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460(v=vs.85).aspx#progress

Comment: What version of C++ and what are you using for the GUI?

Comment: The redistributable package is called `2015 Redistrbutable (x86) -14.0.24215`

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned here, the sample projects you have pointed don't use MFC but WTL, which is an extension of ATL, not currently shipped with Visual Studio. 
So, to make them compile you have to [download WTL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/), install and got rid of some deprecated stuff.

But of course, the **ITaskbarList3** interface can be used in an MFC application, as well.
For starting, here is a brief example:

```
class CMainDialog : public CDialog
{
    // ...
    CComPtr<ITaskbarList3> m_spTaskbarList;
};

BOOL CMainDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    // ...

    HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskbarList, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        __uuidof(ITaskbarList3), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_spTaskbarList));

    if(SUCCEDDED(hr))
    {
       hr = m_spTaskbarList->HrInit();
    }

    // ...
    return TRUE;
}
```

....and of course, do not forget to call **AfxOleInit** in application's class **InitInstance** method.

[ LATER EDIT ]

Sorry, my previous example is wrong! According to documentation, must handle "**TaskbarButtonCreated**" registered message, to be sure that taskbar button is in place, before calling any **ITaskbarList3** method.

```
UINT WM_TASKBAR_BUTTON_CREATED = ::RegisterWindowMessage(_T("TaskbarButtonCreated"));

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainDialog, CDialogEx)
    // ...
    ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(WM_TASKBAR_BUTTON_CREATED, OnTaskbarButtonCreated)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

LRESULT CMainDialog::OnTaskbarButtonCreated(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskbarList, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_ITaskbarList3, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_spTaskbarList));

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // handle error
        return 0;
    }


    hr = m_spTaskbarList->HrInit();
    // ....
    // ... other taskbar list stuff.

    return  0;
}
```

See also this article: [Windows 7: Adding toolbar buttons to taskbar button flyout](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81102/Windows-Adding-toolbar-buttons-to-taskbar-button).

Comment: Thanks, whereabouts would i implement SetProgressState here? Would it be within OnInitDialog or elsewhere?

Comment: May want to call it some other places, in order to show that something happens. Up to your choice.

Comment: `SUCCEDDED`? Really?

Answer (score 2):

The `MESSAGE_HANDLER_EX` macro is a part of WTL. It is defined in `atlcrack.h`.
Most likely you need to get the latest [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/) in order to compile the project in Visual Studio 2015.

As ISun already mentioned the task bar progress can be implemented based on API described in this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460(v=vs.85).aspx#progress

There is a nice wrapper for `ITaskbarList3` interface: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42345/Windows-Goodies-in-C-Taskbar-Progress-and-Status